# No. of elements in the set $\{z\in \mathbb{C}: z^n=-1 \}$

Tags: complex-analysis, elementary-set-theory

I am unable to solve the following problem $$ \text{What is the cardinality of the set}\  \{z\in \mathbb{C}: z^n=-1, z^k\ne -1, \text{for } 0<k<n \}$$

Comment: hint: look at roots of the polynomial $z^n + 1$.  How many does it have and do any of those roots satisfy predicate in your set definition?

Comment: Yes I have tried that, $z=e^{i(\frac{\pi+2k\pi}{n})}\ k=0,1,2,\cdots,n$ but  I am not getting the tota one.

Comment: The title does not reflect the question.

Comment: **Hint:** "Relatively prime"

Answer (score 2):

Suppose that $\zeta$ is a complex number whose $n$th power is $-1$, with $\zeta^k \neq -1$  for $1 \leq k < n$.  Then for all $1 \leq k < n$, we have $\zeta^k \neq \zeta^n$, or in other words $1 \neq \zeta^{n-k}$.  Thus $\zeta$ is not a $k$th root of unity for any $1 \leq k \leq n$.

On the other hand, $\zeta$ is certainly a $2n$th root of unity.  It follows that $2n$ must be the smallest exponent for which $\zeta^{2n} = 1$, or in other words $\zeta$ is a *primitive* $2n$th root of unity; for if $t$ is the smallest number for which $\zeta^t = 1$, then $t$ must divide $2n$ (Lagrange's theorem).  So $t$ divides $2n$ with $n < t \leq 2n$, whence $t = 2n$.

Conversely, any primitive $2n$th root of unity has the property you mentioned: its $n$th power is $-1$, and all lower powers are not $-1$.

So your problem becomes counting the number of primitive $2n$th roots of unity.